# Calculate average based on date range in R

Tags: r

I have a huge database which has financial of companies. I want to calculate the average of column "LEASE_EXP" based on the specific Date range.

let say, I want to calculate the average of LEASE_EXP of all companies (Together) where Column "Bal_Stmt_Date" lies between "1/11/2018" and "31/10/2019"

Please help me with this. I struggling with it since long. I am new to R.
[image: Data set]

```
library(readxl)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\talgotra\\Desktop\\Tech Project\\OperatingLease\\finInfo_q.csv")

start = as.Date("1998-11-01")
end = as.Date("2019-10-31")

mean(subset(transform(df, Bal_Stmt_Date = as.Date(Bal_Stmt_Date, '%m/%d/%Y')), 
            Bal_Stmt_Date >= start & Bal_Stmt_Date <= end, select = LEASE_EXP)[[1]], na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse) # for data manipulation
library(lubridate) # for dates

df <- tribble( # create a sample dataframe
    ~Coded_Name, ~Bal_Stmt_Date, ~LEASE_EXP
    , 1, 20190304, 42
    , 1, 20190305, 42
    , 1, 20190307, 42
    , 2, 20190304, 42
    , 2, 20190305, 42
    , 3, 20190306, 42
    , 3, 20190304, 42
)

df %>% # take the dataframe
    mutate(Bal_Stmt_Date = ymd(Bal_Stmt_Date)) %>% # turn dates into dates
    mutate(timeRangeOfInterest = Bal_Stmt_Date > ymd(20190303) & # create a logical variable identifying the time range of interest
               Bal_Stmt_Date < ymd(20190306)) %>%
    filter(timeRangeOfInterest) %>% # filter out only the time range of interest
    group_by(Coded_Name) %>% # and then per company...
    summarise(sum_LEASE = sum(LEASE_EXP)) # ...calculate the sum
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do :

```
start = as.Date("2018-11-01")
end =  as.Date("2019-10-31")

mean(subset(transform(df, Bal_Stmt_Date = as.Date(Bal_Stmt_Date, '%m/%d/%Y')), 
           Bal_Stmt_Date >= start & Bal_Stmt_Date <= end, select = LEASE_EXP)[[1]], 
           na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or with `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
 filter(between(mdy(Bal_Stmt_Date), start, end)) %>% 
 summarise(mean = mean(LEASE_EXP, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I tried both the mentioned methods. In both menthodsits is giving NaN.

Comment: @AshishTalgotra Add `na.rm = TRUE` , updated the answer.

Comment: @AshishTalgotra In that case, we might need to see your data. Can you update your post with `dput(head(df))` ?

Comment: @AshishTalgotra It is the same code that I have in my post. That is not helpful. Please add data on which you are applying the code. Use `dput(head(df))`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269